# SQL replacing a value in a table and field

Tags: sql

I have a table named BAO.CLASS and a First_name field. Inside the firstnamr field I need to replace  all names that has letter  "A" with number "1" please help

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
UPDATE BAO.CLASS
SET firstname = 1
WHERE firstname like '%A%'
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE BAO.CLASS
SET First_name = 1
WHERE First_name like 'A%'`

Because %A% will replace everything with an A in it, and A% will replace only the names that will start with an A, %A will replace everything that ends with an A.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 0):

You mean to replace all occurences of 'A' with '1'? With most database systems, use:

```
UPDATE BAO.CLASS
SET First_name = REPLACE(First_name, 'A', '1')
WHERE First_name LIKE '%A%'
```

But honestly, first try to make yourself more clear.